# got an error of ''float' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so I am trying to use python to do a equation function

[image]

here is my code:

```
def var_method_1(x):
    n = len(x)
    return [sum(i**2)-1/n*(sum(i)**2) for i in x]/(n-1)
```

so here is the calling code, this is very long calling code, not sure which part direct the error

```
# Test cell: `exercise_1_test`

from random import gauss
from statistics import variance

n = 100000
mu = 1e7
sigma = 1.0

for _ in range(5): # 5 trials
    X = [gauss(mu, sigma) for _ in range(n)]
    var_py = variance(X)
    try:
        del variance
        var_you_0 = var_method_0(X)
        var_you_1 = var_method_1(X)
    except NameError as n:
        if n.args[0] == "name 'variance' is not defined":
            assert False, "Did you try to use `variance()` instead of implementing it from scratch?"
        else:
            raise n
    finally:
        variance = SAVE_VARIANCE

    rel_diff_0 = abs(var_you_0 - var_py) / var_py
    rel_diff_1 = abs(var_you_1 - var_py) / var_py
    print("\nData: n={} samples from a Gaussian with mean {} and standard deviation {}".format(n, mu, sigma))
    print("\tPython's variance function computed {}.".format(var_py))
    print("\tvar_method_0(X) computed {}, with a relative difference of {}.".format(var_you_0, rel_diff_0))
    assert rel_diff_0 <= n*(2.0**(-52)), "The relative difference is larger than expected."
    print("\tvar_method_1(X) computed {}, with a relative difference of {}.".format(var_you_1, rel_diff_1))
    assert rel_diff_1 > n*(2.0**(-52)), "The relative difference is smaller than expected!"

print("\n(Passed!)")
```

and here is the error:

[image]

Comment: Is x an iterable object, such as a list?  Can you provide the calling code?

Comment: @fstop_22 added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong return.

```
return (sum([i**2 for i in x]) - sum(x)**2/n)/(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` takes an iterable, like a list for example to sum over. In this case you're giving sum a float (assuming x is a vector of floats as you're iterating over x).